# Differential equation derivative with respect to parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

I have the following problem :

$x'=x+\lambda(t+x^2)$ , $x(0)=1$, find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \lambda}(t)$ for $\lambda =0$

I am not sure how to move on with this problem or to begin it.

Comment: Is your x' wrt t or lambda.

Comment: I edited your tags to add differential equations.

Comment: Also, do you mean $x(0) = 1$ for all $\lambda$?

Comment: lambda is a parameter. x stands for x(t) everywhere of course

Comment: @Robert Lewis yes.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find derivatives with respect to parameter or initial condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809095/find-derivatives-with-respect-to-parameter-or-initial-condition)