# Euler integration solution from system of ODE's - already estimated values

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, eulers-method

I am currently completing an investigation assignment on modelling the growth of a virus inside of the host. There are 3 ODEs that I am using in the system, all determined by change in t. The differential equations I am trying to solve are below:

$/=[1−(/S)]−_**(_3^2/(_3^2+_3^{50}))$

$S/= -[1−(/S)]$

$d/d=−γ$

$d_1/d=/(+_{50})−__1$

$d_2/d=_*_1−_*_2$

$d_3/d=_*_2.$

[image: values in model]

All values in the system are defined in my program; there is nothing unknown here. So, with relative ease, I created a numerical solution and plotted the graph of I(x) (or any) on matplotlib using python. Below is a table of the first 10 values for all the functions in relation to t:

[image: Table of values]

**Note: initial values on first row where t=0.**

I wanted to use Euler's integration to create a general (estimated) function for I(x) that I can modify easily and investigate changes in constants for my investigation. How would one go about creating a function for $I(x)$? I have initial values and estimated values, so theoretically, it should be easy. I have watched and read so many perfectly good explanations but none seem to fit my method or purpose. Maybe I am ignorant, it should be noted this is my first experience with non-analytical integrals.

Could someone who understands what they are doing in this field, provide some pointers or steps I should take to ultimately get my function of $I,V,S(x)$ in a closed form (estimated of course), that would be good for an inline investigative paper. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is current unclear. Why would want to implement an Euler method while you could use any ODE solver instead?

Comment: @KBS Sorry, this is a very new area for me, I have had no formal education on it. Could you tell me where to find an ODE solver?

Comment: I mean you have plenty of solvers available in Python. Did you Google "ode solver python"? One possibility is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: Could you describe your aim more clearly? There will be no formula for $I(t)$. Numerical integration gives you a function table that can be extended via interpolation. // There are heuristic methods to search in the space of computational graphs for one that closely approximates the function table, but in most cases that is expensive and does not give any further insight. // You can also do the "inverse" to solving the ODE system, modify the function table for $I(t)$ and fit parameters so that the solution is closest to the modified function table.

Comment: Closed form maybe a bit much

Comment: What do you mean by Symbolic estimation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann what I mean is an approximate equation, a model function that I could use that represents the solution to the differential equations (even with a level of error). Do you think there is a way to find an approximate function for $I(t)$ that acknowledges all the variables in the ODE's?

Comment: sorry is that $A_3 $ raised to 50..?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos no sorry I should have explained better. That is the half-maximal value of $A_3$, currently it isn't representative of that concept so the description is redundant. It basically just acts as a latency imposer

Comment: so is $A_3^2 $ a variable?

Comment: [maybe this playlist is of interest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fufF25O4vD8&list=PL8erL0pXF3JZqdlYIfTTyibOqSqwzRdVV)

Comment: It is still not clear what you really want as an answer. Perhaps give a hypothetical example of what you want. For example, do you want something like $I(t)=c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2$ for some constants depending on your parameters, but it won't be an exact answer. How close do you want it to be?

Comment: @Somos Yes that is exactly right. A great answer would be $I(t) = cISt^(2) - {K_{a}*I*A_{3}z }/(A_{3} + 1)z$ If that makes sense, the essential equation which turns out to be a logistic if you ignore the second term, with the constants estimated to represent the solution. The margin of error doesn't necessarily matter, I just need some formal way of deciphering it.

Comment: What you could do is to propose a function that depends on each parameter, that you think fit well the solution, then make numerical estimation of that function based on the numerical solution.

Comment: A better solution will be to make a sensibility analysis of the solution with respect to the parameters. Maybe this will be interesting to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809095/find-derivatives-with-respect-to-parameter-or-initial-condition