# differentiation with respect to parameter

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let $u\geq 0$, $\dot{x}=x-ux^2$, $x(0)=1$.
> Find $\left.\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\right|_{u=0}$.

Just like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809095/find-derivatives-with-respect-to-parameter-or-initial-condition),
the solution $x$ is a function of $u$ and $t$, so it is $x(u,t)$.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}x(u,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(u,t,x(u,t))+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(u,t,x(u,t))\frac{\partial }{\partial u}x(u,t)$$

So:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}x(0,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(0,t,x(0,t))+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(0,t,x(0,t))\frac{\partial }{\partial u}x(0,t)$$

In order to solve my problem, I want to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(0,t,x(0,t))$.

In my class it was said that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=-x^2$. Why do we skip differentiation of $x(u,t)$ and $x^2(u,t)$ even though they depend on $u$, and instead treat them as constants?

Why don't we first do:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(x(u,t)-ux^2(u,t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}x(u,t)-(x^2(u,t)+u^2x(u,t)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}x(u,t)),$$
and then evaluate at $(0,t,x(0,t))$?

It is exactly the same as in the link I pasted above and I can't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an informal explanation. It is easy to get lost in notation.

Let $x_u$ denote the solution to the system with initial condition $x(0)=1$ and input $u$.

You have the equation $\dot{x}_u=f(x_u,u)$ and a nominal trajectory $x_u$ corresponding to some input $u$. The linearised system around $x_u$ is
$\dot{z}_\delta = {\partial f(x_u,u) \over \partial x} z_\delta + {\partial f(x_u,u) \over \partial u} \delta$, where $z_\delta = x_{u+\delta}-x_u$.

The nominal system (with constant input $u(t) = 0$) has the solution $x_0(t) = e^t$. Note that ${\partial f(x_0,0) \over \partial x}(t) = 1$ and
${\partial f(x_0,0) \over \partial u}(t) = -x_0(t)^2$. (The form of the particular partials explains why some of the terms appear to be 'skipped'.)

Hence the linearised system is
$\dot{z}_\delta(t) = z_\delta(t) -x_0(t)^2 \delta(t)$. Solving (assuming I have made no mistakes) gives
$z_\delta(t) = e^t z_\delta(0) - \int_0^t e^{t-s} \delta(s) ds = - \int_0^t e^{t-s} \delta(s) ds$ (since $z_\delta(0) = 0$).

Formally, $({\partial x_u \over \partial u} \delta) (t) = - \int_0^t e^{t-s} \delta(s) ds$.

Just for some informal clarification, the $\partial x, \partial u$ in the ${\partial f(x_0,0) \over \partial x}$ and
${\partial f(x_0,0) \over \partial u}$ are 'scalars' where as the $\partial u$ in ${\partial x_u \over \partial u}$ is a function.

Comment: How can you differentiate with respect to scalar?

Comment: The function $(x,u) \mapsto f(x,u)$ is map from the scalars $x,u$ to the reals. The (Frechet) derivative ${\partial x_u \over \partial u}$ is a linear map from the space of inputs to trajectories.